# Как проверить соединение с интернетом?

Tags: delphi, веб-программирование, delphi-7

Сейчас банально я сделал:

```
uses winInet;

function IsConnectedToInternet: Boolean;
var
  dwConnectionTypes: DWORD;
begin
  dwConnectionTypes:= INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM or INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN or INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY;
  Result := InternetGetConnectedState(@dwConnectionTypes, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsConnectedToInternet
    then ShowMessage('Соединение есть')
    else ShowMessage('Нету соединения');
end;
```

но это видимо работает только в том случае если интернет напрямую идет, а ни через локальную сеть, тобишь сейчас у меня получается так что всегда возвращает TRUE, даже если я вырубил соединение (именно с Интернет). Как сделать чтобы не было зависимости от локальных сетей?

Черт с ним, это я вообще удалил, сделал через try except, т.к. просто нужно одну страницу распарсить:

```
procedure getHTML(url:string);
begin
     try
      try
       html:=Utf8ToAnsi(Form1.idHttp1.Get(url));
       form1.Label2.Caption:='Updated!';
       form1.Timer2.Enabled:=false;
     except
      Form1.Label1.Caption:='Нету соединения с данным URL';
      Form1.Timer2.Enabled:=true;
     end;

     finally

     end;

     if (Form1.Timer2.Enabled) then
      form1.Label2.Caption:='Timer 2 Working NOW'
       else form1.Label2.Caption:='Timer 2 in Off';
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
getHTML('http://site.ru');
showmessage('timer 2 work');
end;
```

беда в том что таймер продолжает работать когда я включаю соединение. А логика такова что таймер должен остановиться если я его включу (соединение).

Comment: как это ни странно, но TRUE оно мне выдало даже когда я локальную сеть вырубил.

Comment: Во-первых ваша функция совершенно неверно работает с out параметром. А во-вторых, задача не столь тривиальная, как кажется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня тоже возникала такая задача. Было(и есть) приложение, которое должно было проверять само себя "на активированность", для этого надо было лезть в глобальную БД и искать свой ID там. Но если интернет подключен не был, то программа должна была предупреждать пользователя. Я недолго думал по этому поводу, хотя сначала даже пытался что-то делать с сокетами. Но решение, имхо, было очевидно: обращаться к какому-либо глобальному объекту в блоке `TRY->EXCEPT->END` и если исключительная ситуация возникала, то это был знак, что доступа к интернету не было. Обращаться можно к какому либо сайту, например, получать контент с одной из его страниц. Это можно сделать с помощью TidHTTP. Еще можно пинговать глобальную БД и т.д и т.п

**UPD:**

Я лично проверял соединение с интернетом, пингуя MySQL сервер так:

```
if Zconnection1.Ping = false then  // Если соединения с интернетом нет, то
begin
try
// пытаемся подключиться, как только он появится
ZConnection1.Reconnect;
ZTable1.Active:=true;
if form1.ZConnection1.Connected then showmessage('!!!'); // оповещение об успехе
except
end;
end;
```

**P.S**
ZConnection, ZTable и прочие Z-обьекты - это Zeos набор компонентов для работы с MySQL серверами. Шаблон вышеприведенного кода используйте в таймере с интервалом не менее 0.8 секунд.

Comment: я это и пытаюсь сделать, через try except+заморочка с таймером, но когда я включаю соединение, то функция продолжает считать что нету соединения, см. дополню вопрос.

Comment: "пинговать глобальную БД" звучит почти как грабить корованы ;-)

Comment: > звучит почти как грабить корованы

от слова корова?;)

Comment: дополнение видели?

Comment: Нет, от слов [Здраствуйте. Я, Кирилл.](http://images.wikia.com/fallout/images/e/e5/HappyTrailsCaravanCompany.png) :-D @Tolbase, увы, в частном случае проблема тривиальна и уже много раз обсуждалась.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить доступность сервера с IP 8.8.8.8 - гугловский DNS. Будет достаточно надежно.

Comment: На самом деле нет, недостаточно. [Вот как делают в Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017)

Comment: Чудесные алгоритмы определения состояния сети от Microsoft в Win7 показывают мне "наличие интернета" даже когда его нет физически и быть не может.

Comment: Но за статью спасибо, весьма любопытно.

Comment: Гуглелюбский способ тоже не слишком надежен, что и делает вопрос интересным в общем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Пропингуйте какой-нибудь известный сервер, как вариант.